# Autoclicker times out when, page needs to be refreshed?

Tags: vb.net, browser, refresh

I have created an autoclicker that once someone hits a button, it sends requests to the submit button on a page to be clicked about once a second. It works great, and lasts about 30 minutes, but it still times and becomes unresponsive. The current script I'm working with seems good:

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        Timer1.Interval = 40
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
        Timer1.Interval = 100
    Else
        Timer1.Interval = 500
    End If



    If ((WebBrowser1.IsBusy)) Then




    Else
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("NewGamertag").SetAttribute("value", txtTurbo.Text)

        Timer1.Enabled = True

    End If



End Sub
```

Where Timer1 has the code to autoclick the submit button:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("claimIt").InvokeMember("Click")

End Sub
```

So now I need to know how to refresh it every X seconds. I created a new timer called RefreshPage, and gave it these principals:

```
Private Sub RefreshPage_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RefreshPage.Tick
    WebBrowser1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

The only problem is, now when I enable RefreshPage (RefreshPage.Enabled = True) in my Button1, it tells me this: http://gyazo.com/4c9f83a48d6262b26757281512bee35c
I have no idea what this means or how to fix it, my best guess is that it tries to refresh as it tries to claim thus meaning the button is not findable in the source. (Right when I open the program and press the button the program becomes unresponsive)

Any help?